# Eloquent Relationship in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have been working on integrating Laravel's Eloquent relationship on my Code Igniter project. So I followed the steps in http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added . Everything is working fine. But When I started mapping relationships, I get error like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Products::hasMany()
```

Following is my Product model file

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Product extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "products";

public function getActive(){
    return Product::where('status', 1)->get();
}

public function Price(){
    return $this->hasMany('Price', 'product_id');
}
}
```

And this is my Price model

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Price extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "price"; 
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call it:

```
$product = Product::with('price')->get();
```

or

```
$product = Product::all();
$productPrice = $product[0]->price;
```

not

```
 $product = Product::Price();
```

Some info:
If you have a 1:n relation you can define it better "prices":

```
public function prices(){
    return $this->hasMany('Price', 'product_id');
}
```

it is better for reading if a product has more then one price:

```
$product = Product::with('prices')->find(1);
```